# Is there a polynomial long division proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is short and simple but also needs clarification. How is it that you can divide only a single term into a polynomial, and get the same result as if you were to divide both? I've asked this question on Reddit but got less than satisfactory responses. I think maybe they misunderstood my confusion.

I understand how you can divide a relatively complex expression by a single term, (let's say $\dfrac{x^2+3x+2}x$), what I don't understand is how you can divide only a single term from the denominator, into the numerator, and still get a valid quotient. If we're asking the question "How many times does a $(x-1)$ go into $(x^2+3x+2)$?", shouldn't there be a process of dividing both $x$, and $-1$ into the expression...? Maybe a broader question would be, what is the correct way to think about dividing a value by two different values?

Comment: You can divide $317$ by $5$ and get some remainder. You can also divide $317$ by $5-1$ and get another remainder. This has nothing to do with dividing $317$ by $5$ or by $-1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, what...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can divide polynomials as long as you take the coefficient to be in a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) (essentially that means that the non zero elements are invertible). The precise result is that given polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ there exist *unique* polynomials $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ such that
$$
A(x)=B(x)Q(x)+R(x)
$$
and *the degree of $R(x)$ is smaller than degree of $B(x)$* (this is actually the key point).

In your example you get
$$
x^2+3x+2=(x-1)(x+4)+6.
$$